# Connection to remote host was lost - 2 websocket conncetions - Randomly getting disconnected

Tags: python, websocket

I recently started getting websocket data from my data provider. They provide 2 endpoints: 1 for quotes and 1 for trades. You can subscribe up to 50 symbols at once. So if I create a connection to 1 of the endpoints I have no disconnects whatsoever. I ran this last week for like 8 hrs without any disconnect. The problem occurs when I try using 2 endpoints at once, both the quotes and trades. I split the subscribtions 25 quotes and 25 trades so it's not an issue of over subscribing. It seems to randomly disconnect me and I have no idea why. Once it was after 2.5 minutes and the next time it was after 15 minutes. I am using Python to get this data. I tried googling for an answer and thought it might have to do with threading whatever that means but am not sure. Have seen similar questions on here but no answers really...Would apprectiate any help. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
import websocket, ssl
import json
from EOD_API_KEY import API_KEY
import time as t
from datetime import datetime
import time as ts

#TODAYS DATE
TODAYS_DATE = datetime.now()
TODAYS_DATE = TODAYS_DATE.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
# print(TODAYS_DATE)

# COMMANDS
# ws.send() SEND
# ws.recv() RECEIVED
# ws.close() CLOSE


# URL
QUOTES_URL = f"wss://ws.eodhistoricaldata.com/ws/us-quote?api_token={API_KEY}"
TRADES_URL = f"wss://ws.eodhistoricaldata.com/ws/us?api_token={API_KEY}"

# CREATE CONNECTION
# websocket.enableTrace(True)
wsqc = websocket.create_connection(QUOTES_URL, timeout=None, skip_utf8_validation=True, sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
wstc = websocket.create_connection(TRADES_URL, timeout=None, skip_utf8_validation=True, sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})

# GET LIST
txt_file_DIR = 'C:\\DATA\\WEBSOCKETS\\SCAN_LIST\\'
txt_file_name = 'WEBSOCKETS'
FULL_txt_path = txt_file_DIR + txt_file_name + '.txt'

# CREATE LIST
TICKER_LIST = []

# OPEN TICKER LIST
open_list = open(FULL_txt_path, 'r')
for line in open_list:
    stripped = line.strip()
    TICKER_LIST.append(stripped)
open_list.close()

# DEBUGGING LIST
# TICKER_LIST = ['AAPL']
print(TICKER_LIST)

# SUBSCRIBE TO QUOTES
for TICKER in TICKER_LIST:
    # JSON SUBSCRIPTION MESSAGES
    SUBSCRIBE = json.dumps({"action": "subscribe", "symbols": f"{TICKER}"})

    # SUBSCRIBE TO STREAMING DATA
    wsqc.send(SUBSCRIBE)

# SUBSCRIBE TO TRADES
for TICKER in TICKER_LIST:
    # JSON SUBSCRIPTION MESSAGES
    SUBSCRIBE = json.dumps({"action": "subscribe", "symbols": f"{TICKER}"})

    # SUBSCRIBE TO STREAMING DATA
    wstc.send(SUBSCRIBE)

# CREATE JSON FILE TO STORE T&S DATA
QUOTES_DIR_OUT = "C:\\DATA\\WEBSOCKETS\\QUOTES\\STOCKS\\US\\JSON\\"
TRADES_DIR_OUT = "C:\\DATA\\WEBSOCKETS\\TRADES\\STOCKS\\US\\JSON\\"

FILE_QUOTES_NAME = f"Quotes_{TODAYS_DATE}.json"
FILE_TRADES_NAME = f"Trades_{TODAYS_DATE}.json"

FULL_DIR1 = QUOTES_DIR_OUT + FILE_QUOTES_NAME
FULL_DIR2 = TRADES_DIR_OUT + FILE_TRADES_NAME

JSON_QUOTES_LIST = []
JSON_TRADES_LIST = []

# OPEN FILE
JSON_QUOTES_FILE = open(FULL_DIR1, 'a')
JSON_TRADES_FILE = open(FULL_DIR2, 'a')

timer = 10
# RECIEVE MESSAGE

# TIME
CLOSE_TIME = "22:01"
start_time_ts = ts.time()
start_time = datetime.now()
print(start_time_ts)
start_time_str = start_time.strftime("%H:%M")
print("Current Time =", start_time_str)

# 1 - LOGIN
LOGIN_CHECK_STATUS = False
try:
    quotes_reply = wsqc.recv()
    trades_reply = wstc.recv()

    decoded_quotes_reply = json.loads(quotes_reply)
    decoded_trades_reply = json.loads(trades_reply)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Login exception: {e}")

# LOGIN STATIS CHECK
if (decoded_quotes_reply["status_code"] == 200) and (decoded_trades_reply["status_code"] == 200):
    LOGIN_CHECK_STATUS = True
    print(f"Login Status Check: {LOGIN_CHECK_STATUS}")
else:
    print(f"Login Status Check: {LOGIN_CHECK_STATUS}")

while start_time != CLOSE_TIME and LOGIN_CHECK_STATUS:
# while timer != 0 and LOGIN_CHECK_STATUS:  # DEBUGGING

    # GET RESPONSE - QUOTES
    try:
        quotes_reply = wsqc.recv()
        decoded_quotes_reply = json.loads(quotes_reply)

        print(decoded_quotes_reply)
        JSON_QUOTES_LIST.append(decoded_quotes_reply)

    # Quotes Exception
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Quotes Receive Error: {e}.")
        end_time_ts = ts.time()
        break

    # GET RESPONSE - TRADES
    try:
        trades_reply = wstc.recv()
        decoded_trades_reply = json.loads(trades_reply)

        print(decoded_trades_reply)
        JSON_TRADES_LIST.append(decoded_trades_reply)

    # Trades Exception
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Trades Receive Error: {e}")
        end_time_ts = ts.time()
        break

    # FOR DEBUGGING
    # t.sleep(1)
    # timer = timer - 1

elapsed_time = (end_time_ts - start_time_ts) / 60
print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time} seconds.")

# CLOSE CONNECTION
wsqc.close()
wstc.close()
print("Connections Closed")

# Output JSON file
JSON_QUOTES_FILE.write(json.dumps(JSON_QUOTES_LIST, indent=4))
JSON_TRADES_FILE.write(json.dumps(JSON_TRADES_LIST, indent=4))
print("Files outputted")

# CLOSE JSON FILE
JSON_QUOTES_FILE.close()
JSON_TRADES_FILE.close()
```

Comment: UPDATE: Managed to get this working via Muliprocessing